# Setup laravel 4

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-4

I'm new to laravel and I'm trying to setup Laravel 4, using (bit outdated) http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-setup-laravel-4/

I have setup composer globally. When I run:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/laravel/framework.git l4
$ cd l4
$ composer install
```

..all seems to install successfully (I don't get any errors), but exists no app dir:

```
drwxr-xr-x   3 dirkpostma  staff    102 Mar 24 19:54 build
-rw-r--r--   1 dirkpostma  staff   2794 Mar 24 19:54 composer.json
-rw-r--r--   1 dirkpostma  staff  33306 Mar 24 19:55 composer.lock
-rw-r--r--   1 dirkpostma  staff    847 Mar 24 19:54 phpunit.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 dirkpostma  staff   8677 Mar 24 19:54 readme.md
drwxr-xr-x   3 dirkpostma  staff    102 Mar 24 19:54 src
drwxr-xr-x  27 dirkpostma  staff    918 Mar 24 19:54 tests
drwxr-xr-x  13 dirkpostma  staff    442 Mar 24 19:55 vendor
```

Is this correct..? Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You're cloning the wrong repository.

```
git clone -b develop git://github.com/laravel/laravel.git myapp
cd myapp
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
composer.phar install
```

Read:

### - [Installing and updating Laravel 4](http://niallobrien.me/2013/03/installing-and-updating-laravel-4/)

Answer (score 0):

To answer myself:

The used git URL is wrong. You can either:

1. Follow [these instructions](http://four.laravel.com/docs/installation). This uses a zip-archive that's (I guess) build every few days.
2. Clone the develop branch of laravel and then run composer install:

   $ git clone -b develop git@github.com:laravel/laravel.git

   $ composer install

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
git clone -o laravel -b develop https://github.com/laravel/laravel.git project-name

cd project-name

php composer.phar install
```